# Spring Batch Multithreaded Execution keeps going on even after no data is present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, threadpoolexecutor

I have a Spring Batch Project where I am using a `AbstractPaginatedItemReader` to read from a Paginated SOAP API. I am using a task executor to run the step asynchronously. 
 
Now the even if the API has 2 pages of data available, the reader continues to query the API with page number 3, 4 and so on until all the available data has been written. 
 
I am setting the `pageSize` to the number of records I am expecting in each page which is 5. But even when the API is sending 0 records the reader still calls for the next page.

I tried running without the task executor, and the reader is only querying only the 2 pages which are available.

Anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: If it runs correctly in a single thread it must be something in your code that prevents it from running correctly in multi threaded mode.

Comment: I runs okay in MultiThreaded mode also, only thing is it's making unnecessary empty reads, when the data from previous read is being processed or written to a database.

Comment: So it doesn't run ok. Looks like your reader is wrong for concurrent access, at least the check if it should read or not.